# svn: E200019: ra_serf was compiled for serf 1.3.4 but loaded an incompatible 1.1.1 library

Tags: macos, svn, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I'm on Mac OS 10.9.2 and I had been using subversion installed via Homebrew. That had been working so far, but since I upgraded to Mac OS 10.9.2 I've been running into issues with it. I've been able to fix all of them, except for this one. Here's what I've done so far:

```
brew install --with-python --build-from-source subversion
==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=subversion/subversion-1.8.8.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/subversion-1.8.8.tar.bz2
==> Patching
patching file subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Makefile.PL.in
Hunk #1 succeeded at 76 (offset 7 lines).
patching file configure.ac
==> Downloading http://serf.googlecode.com/svn/src_releases/serf-1.3.4.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/subversion--serf-1.3.4.tar.bz2
```

Then it compiles just fine. There are a couple of lines of output that may or may not hint at a possible reason for the issue I'm experiencing, but I'm not sure it's related:

```
Install file: "libserf-1.a" as "/usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.8.8/libexec/serf/lib/libserf-1.a"
Install file: "libserf-1.1.3.0.dylib" as "/usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.8.8/libexec/serf/lib/libserf-1.1.3.0.dylib"
install_name_tool -id /usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.8.8/libexec/serf/lib/libserf-1.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.8.8/libexec/serf/lib/libserf-1.1.3.0.dylib
```

Next, trying to run subversion returns the error that I haven't been able to fix:

```
~: svn
svn: E200019: ra_serf was compiled for serf 1.3.4 but loaded an incompatible 1.1.1 library
```

**Which one is the incompatible 1.1.1 library and how do I fix this?**

[Updated on Mar 13 with the solution]

**The Solution**
Although Homebrew doesn’t provide Serf as a separate package anymore and instead includes it in SVN as a private package, the old version was still installed on my machine from the original installation a long time ago. Running `brew remove serf` did fix the problem.